# Having trouble using PREPARE and EXECUTE

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm first checking if table is present. If not present, then I'm creating one & then inserting data into it.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `myDb`.`InsertData`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `InsertData`(
IN _P1 VARCHAR(255),
IN _P2 DATETIME,
IN _P3 TEXT,
IN _TableName VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
DECLARE TableCount INT(1);

SET TableCount = (SELECT COUNT(table_name)
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'myDb' AND table_name = _TableName);

IF(TableCount = 0) THEN
    SET @s = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myDb`.`',_TableName,'` ( 
     `P1` VARCHAR(255),`P2` DATETIME, `P3` TEXT ;'); 
    PREPARE stmt3 FROM @s; 
    SELECT stmt3;
    EXECUTE stmt3; 
END IF;
SET @s = CONCAT('INSERT INTO `myDb`.`',_TableName,'` ( P1, P2, P3)
VALUES (' + _P1 + ',' + _P2 + ',' + _P3 + ')'); 
PREPARE stmt3 FROM @s; 
EXECUTE stmt3; 

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The procedure gets compiled successfully, but when I run it, it gives me error:

```
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL     
server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an `)`

```
SET @s = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myDb`.`',_TableName,'` ( 
            `P1` VARCHAR(255),`P2` DATETIME, `P3` TEXT );'); 
                                                       ^----------here
```

Comment: Thanks. Missed it. Now it is giving me error: Unknown column 'stmt3' in 'field list'. Never used prepare statement before!

Comment: remove the line `SELECT stmt3;`